# ¿Como doy formato filas(observaviones) , columnas (variables) a este archivo?

Tags: r, dataset

Estoy pensando como dar el formato típico de dataset al[1](https://datos.madrid.es/sites/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=71359583a773a510VgnVCM2000001f4a900aRCRD&vgnextchannel=374512b9ace9f310VgnVCM100000171f5a0aRCRD) siguiente documento excell,  la única opción que se me ha ocurrido es transponer manualmente en excell, alguna idea en Excell o R ? La idea es tener en cada fila un barrio o distrito de madrid en las columnas las diferentes variables.
(es el dataset del enlace en formato excell "Estudio de indicadores de distritos y barrios 2017")

Comment: Hola agustin marin, bienvenido. Es de gran ayuda que enlaces a tus datos, sin embargo y para asegurar recibir una respuesta adecuada sería muy bueno que describieras de manera precisa cuál es la estructura de datos que esperas obtener. En concreto ¿qué representaría cada fila? ¿Y cada columna? En cualquier caso, es posible hacerlo en R sin manipular previamente el Excel, de ese modo también automatizarías el proceso para importar el versiones futuras del archivo.

Comment: Hola , muchas gracias por tu recomendación. Ya edite la pregunta para quedara mas claro la forma que quiero dar al dataset. Consistirá en tener en cada columna diferentes variables y en cada fila distritos y barrios de Madrid.

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que quieres que cada fila sea una unidad territorial (distrito, barrio, etc.) y cada columna un atributo o variable medido en esa unidad territorial. Esto sería (aproximadamente) tidydata, en el sentido de Wickham. Si buscas otra estructura para los datos deberías editar tu pregunta para hacerlo explícito.

Va una primera aproximación al problema, que al menos adelanta algo el trabajo al producir un data.frame transpuesto y con nombre razonablemente apropiados. Definitivamente requiere más limpieza, mejores nombres, etc. Limpiar archivos de excel es muy complicado porque cada uno tiene la estructura que le dio quien lo hizo y siempre es necesaria una solución ad hoc, así que te quedan unas cuantas horas por delante ;)

## Aclaraciones

1. Tuve que transformar fuera de R el archivo a xlsx, no pude leerlo como .xls
2. El script trabaja con la primera hoja del excel (CENTRO). Sin embargo **si** funciona bien y -principalmente- **si** todas las hojas tienen la misma estructura podrías reproducirlo en cada hoja y luego unir cada parte en un data.frame completo.

## Código

La función más importante es `transpose` de `data.table`. El resto es manejo de nombres de fila y columna.

```
library(readxl)
library(data.table)

datos <- read_excel("excel_maldito/IndicadoresDistritos2017_2.xlsx", sheet = "CENTRO", skip = 1) #Importante skip = 1 para mantener nombres de columna.

datos <- rbind(names(datos), datos) #Paso los nombres de columna como primera fila, si no transpose los pierde.
datos_t <- data.table::transpose(datos) #Transpongo los datos: ahora las columnas son filas.
colnames(datos_t) <- datos_t[1, ]      #Paso primera fila a nombres de columna, de este modo los conservé
datos_t <- datos_t[2:nrow(datos_t),]   #Y elimino esa primera fila, ahora es redundante
datos_t_limpio <- datos_t[ ,!sapply(lapply(datos_t, is.na), all)]  #Elimino todas las columnas que solo contienen NA.
names(datos_t_limpio)[307] <- "Capítulo Presupuestario"  #En en los datos produce un NA
datos_t_limpio <- datos_t_limpio[1:16, ] #ATENCION: podría fallar en otras horas con más o menos unidades territoriales
```

## Pendientes

- El excel tiene valores absolutos y proporciones. Se debería tomar una decisión sobre que hacer con eso. **Si** las proporciones se pueden calcular a partir de los valores absolutos se las podría eliminar.
- No estoy seguro de que los datos de presupuesto tengan la misma estructura que el resto. Se debería verificar y eliminar/reformatear dependiendo del caso.
- No sé muy bien que pintan las filas `X__10` a `X__12`. Creo que están repetidas o tienen información irrelevante, por eso las elimino, pero habría que verificarlo cuidadosamente y **ver que pasa en las restantes hojas que pueden tener más o menos barrios**.

Luego me dices si te acerca a la solución. Limpiar exceles es doloroso, suerte y paciencia.